# How to describe this application behaviors?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I would like to find a js library that allow me to do similar things as same as gmail:

[image]

They got a textarea, when you typing it, it search things and provide a list of contract list for you to choose from, when you tab it, it becomes a separate element, you can delete it by pressing the `X`.  I know it is not come with textarea, or standard html element, how can I describe / search related lib on the web? Any keywords ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stackexchange tags and Pinterest filters work similarly.

I did a google search with

> "tags interface" filter

I searched both normal and images.

The images quickly allow you to focus in on an interface.
For example, the jQuery plugin [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-tags-input) jumped out.

A further search on the following brought up more google images which seem right on.

> "Tags Input"

I suggest this is better suited for the UX - User Experience StackExchange site. There is one discussion I found [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/tags-massive-amounts-of-tags-and-a-sane-interface-to-use-them)

Good luck. I will likely write something myself in the not too distant future. It is a user friendly interface.